# How to delete n number of rows at a time in SQL server from my trim stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that can delete all the data that are past a certain date. But I want to add the functionality so that it only deletes 1000 rows at a time.

I have something like this

```
USE [databaseName]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LogTrim]
                       (
                          @DaysToKeep             INT = 28
                          --@Blocks               INT = 1000 --??
                       )
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Declarations
---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Standard Variables
DECLARE
        @Error            INT
       ,@ErrorCode        INT
       ,@ExitCode         INT
       ,@ProcedureLineNbr INT
       ,@ProcedureName    VARCHAR(30)
       ,@rc               INT          
       ,@Rowcount         INT

-- Local Variables
DECLARE
         @DateToKeep       DATETIME
        ,@TimePeriodToKeep INT
        ,@DeletedRowCount  DEC
        ,@Message1         VARCHAR(60)
        ,@Message2         VARCHAR(60)
        ,@ERRPARAMETER     INT
        ,@ERRUNEXPECTED    INT

---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Initializations
---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Standard Variables
SELECT
        @ExitCode          = 0
       ,@ProcedureName     = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
       ,@ProcedureLineNbr  = 0

-- Local Variables
SET @TimePeriodToKeep      =  ABS( @DaysToKeep )
SET @DateToKeep            =  DATEADD( dd, -@TimePeriodToKeep, ( CONVERT( DATETIME, CONVERT( CHAR( 10 ), GETDATE( ), 120 ), 120 ) ) )
SET @ERRPARAMETER          =  200110
SET @ERRUNEXPECTED         =  200104

PRINT ( 'Oldest date to keep = ' + CONVERT( VARCHAR, @DateToKeep ) )
---------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------
BEGIN TRANSACTION DeleteRows

DELETE
FROM
         tableName
WHERE
         CreateDate < @DateToKeep --TimeStart

SET @Rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
SET @Error    = @@ERROR

IF ( @Error = 0 )
BEGIN  -- @Error = 0

    COMMIT TRANSACTION DeleteRows
    SET   @Message2 = 'Number of rows deleted = ' + CONVERT( VARCHAR, @Rowcount )
    PRINT @Message2

END  -- @Error = 0
ELSE
BEGIN  --  @Error <> 0

    SET @ErrorCode = @ERRUNEXPECTED
    SET @Message1  = CONVERT( VARCHAR, @Error ) + ' (Delete rows from EBCPDiagnosticLog)'
    RAISERROR( @ErrorCode, 16, 1, @ProcedureName, @Message1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION DeleteRows
    GOTO ErrorHandler

END  --  @Error <> 0

---------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------
GOTO ExitProc

---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Error Handler
---------------------------------------------------------------------
ErrorHandler:
   SELECT @ExitCode =  -100
   GOTO ExitProc

---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Exit Procedure
---------------------------------------------------------------------
ExitProc:
   RETURN (@ExitCode)
```

Right now the trim will delete all the data at the same time. But I want to add a parameter called Blocks that will delete based on the input parameter or default of 28. Thanks.

Comment: 1. Why; 2. Did you search first? There are many solutions online

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `WHILE` loop, that will loop until the @@ROWCOUNT from your delete statement is less than 1000 (indicating that there are no more rows left to delete)

```
DECLARE @delete_count int;
SET @delete_count = 1000;

WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
    -- Delete the records
    DELETE 
        TOP (@delete_count)
    FROM
        dbo.EBCPDiagnosticLob
    WHERE
        CreateDate < @DateToKeep;

    -- If there are no more rows to delete, then break out of the loop
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT < @delete_count)
        BREAK;
END;
```

Comment: No, do it without `SELECT 1`. `WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN DELETE ...; IF @@ROWCOUNT < 10000 BREAK; END;`

Comment: I'm confused. shouldn't I delete number of @@ROWCOUNT 1000 rows at a time?

Comment: @ErikE Thanks, I've updated the answer to use that method. Is there a performance reason for that, or is it simply to keep @@ROWCOUNT references within the loop (that's why I like your method)? By not looping based on @@ROWCOUNT, there's not a chance of a later developer accidentally putting another query between `SELECT 1` and the while loop.

Comment: @jjss My mistake; I misread your question's "1000" as "10000".

Comment: The `SELECT 1` returns a rowset. This can be a problem by itself, but additionally violates standard programming practice, that we shouldn't run statements that have no meaning just to get their side-effects. And yes, it's not immediately apparent what the `SELECT 1` is for, and someone could take it out or accidentally put another statement in (that might usually have rows so a failure might not occur for a while, leading to difficulty diagnosing it). The performance reason is that on average, 999 times out 1000, you don't need an extra loop in the `WHILE`.

Comment: That is, only if the number of rows deleted is an exact multiple of 1000, then  you need an extra `DELETE` statement with 0 rows returned to detect this state. But if you delete 999 rows, then you can exit the loop because you know you've deleted them all. The only additional improvement I'd make is to change 1000 to a variable so no one changes just one of them and not the other one.

Comment: @ErikE Thanks, all of that makes sense. That @@ROWCOUNT "trick" was some left over trivia from a long time ago, that I never really questioned. Most of my work in loops is done based on column values, rather than @@ROWCOUNT, so I haven't put much thought into it. I'm always glad when poor habits are weeded out of my practices, so thanks for taking the time to point this out! I'll leave the 1000 variable portion to the OP.

Comment: @ErikE Variable added, to make the answer more complete. :) Thanks again for the tips.

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit. Relational databases have rows, not records. It's always best to model best practice in answers, and putting in schema names is best practice for various reasons, so I recommend using `dbo` in answers if a user leaves it out of their sample code.

Comment: @ErikE . I'm getting an error of "Cannot use a BREAK statement outside the scope of a WHILE statement."

Comment: @jjss So put it inside a `WHILE` block? If you need help, create a new question, and tag me with a link.